# React Hooks: useState() makes all children component re-rendered although the change doesn't affect some of them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Okay. Here is my situation. I have a big component called `TheForm`. In `TheForm`, there are the following children: `TextEditor`, `TagInput`, `TipCard` - this gives the advice how to write a good form and `Preview`:

```
const TheForm = () => {
  const [parag1, writeParag1] = useState("");
  const [parag2, writeParag2] = useState("");
  const [tags, updateTags] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div>
     <TipCard>Some suggestion here...</TipCard>
     Paragraph One: <TextEditor onInput={writeParag1}/>
     Paragraph One: <TextEditor onInput={writeParag2}/>
     Add tags: <TagInput onInput={updateTags}/>
     Preview Mode: <Preview />
     <button>Submit</button>
     <button>Reset</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The `TextEditor` contains a `<textarea>`, some buttons to format text, everytimes the value of the `<textarea>` changes, the proper state in `TheForm` is updated. Same for `TagInput`.

The `Preview` will take the state values and render them in preview mode (just like Stack Overflow ask a question).

The problem here is when one of the states is updated, it causes all the children re-rendered, even they are not using that state and even I used the `React.memo` for the component.

I know that when the state changes, it make the component re-rendered, so the children of the component are re-rendered too.

So how can I avoid that? I know that I can move the states down to the children, but if I do it, the `Preview` can not access those value. Redux can solve this problem, but is it too much to use Redux here, I mean those states are not shared with other component so using Redux is too much?

Comment: You can use `React.memo` for functional component or `PureComponent` for class component

Comment: `React.memo` doesn't solve the problem. I used it but the children keep being updated.

Comment: You need to use it for your children component not for `TheForm` component

Comment: Yes, I used it for the children.

Comment: Please share full `TheForm` code and your children code

Comment: It's the reduce form of my code, if you want to see the hundred-line form so here is the link: https://gist.github.com/PhanDungTri/08146be148eef5f3c340f37246533059

Comment: why do you want to avoid children being re-rendered? what's overall goal?

Comment: because the children stay the same every rendering, so re-rendering them causes the performance problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just how React works - it run render function every time state is changed and it cause all children to re-render too, no matter are they depended on changed state or not.

If you would like to avoid re-render of a component, you can make it *pure*, e.g. wrap it with `React.memo`. So you have to wrap each child in order to prevent it re-render.

Pure components shallow compare `props` to determinate if it safe to skip re-render requested from a parent. It means, you have to not only wrap children to `memo` but ensure the props passed to them is persistent each time of render. 
Usually it means you should memoize callback like 
`onInput={el => updateTitle(el.target.value)}` with `useMemo` or `useCallback`
and avoid, flatten or memoize objects like `previewMode={{ title, description, codeBlock, tagList }}` otherwise they will be re-created each time and it will invalidate shallow-compare optimisation

Comment: I think I will stick with Redux, because those states are app data, not the UI states, so I think it is fine if I give them a little space in the store.